# Why Fourier series is represented in 2 different ways?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Why Fourier series is sometimes represented as $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}[a_r \cos(\frac{2\pi rx}{L}) + b_r \sin(\frac{2\pi r x}{L})],$$ but sometimes $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}[a_r \cos(rx) + b_r \sin(rx)].$$ Why do people define it in two different ways? Are they equivalent? How to prove that they are?

Comment: Do you mean $\cos(rx)$ and $\sin(rx)$ in the second series? Also, where have you seen the second definition?

Comment: @Aha: see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399900/fourier-series-on-general-interval-a-b

Comment: Because sometimes $L$ is equal to $2\pi$ and sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be  a non zero real number. In general, you have the Fourier series expansion on the interval $[-L,L]$

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[a_n \cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right) + b_n \sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\right)\right],$$

$$a_{0}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}{f(x)dx}$$

$$a_{n}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}{f(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right)dx}$$

$$b_{n}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}{f(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right)dx}$$

> When $L=\pi$, you have in particular the Fourier series expansion in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$
>   $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{r=1}^{\infty}[a_r \cos(nx) + b_r \sin(nx)].$$
>   $$a_{0}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)dx}$$
>   $$a_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\cos\left(\frac{\pi nx}{\pi}\right)dx}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\cos(nx)dx}$$
>   $$b_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{\pi}\right)dx}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\sin(nx)dx}$$

Even, you can do the same in any interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ (under some hypothesis of course):

> Let's call $$L=\frac{b-a}{2}$$
>   $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[a_n \cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}\right) + b_n \sin\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{b-a}\right)\right],$$
>   but in this case the Fourier coefficients are:
>   $$a_{0}=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)dx}$$
>   $$a_{n}=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}\right)dx}$$
>   $$b_{n}=\frac{2}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}{f(x)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{b-a}\right)dx}$$

Comment: What is the point of having so many different forms?

Comment: It depends where you want to avaluate the Fourier series. This for which values of $x$ you want to approximate the function $f$ by it's Fourier series.