# Is the sum of a Fourier series periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

If a Fourier series converges, will it converge to a periodic function? It seems logical since it is a trigonometric series. But often we are told to derive the Fourier series of functions like $x^2$, which are not periodic.

Comment: When you derive the Fourier series of $x^2$, what you are actually doing is deriving the Fourier series of the periodic function whose restriction to $[-\pi, \pi]$ equals $x^2$. If you want to do Fourier analysis with non-periodic functions defined on $\mathbb R$, you need the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of a Fourier series is periodic. As said in a comment, when people talk about the Fourier series of $x^2$,  they actually mean the Fourier series of this function:

[image: periodic]

which is the result of restricting $x^2$ to the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$ (or whatever interval you use for Fourier series), and then extending that periodically.

Comment: "or whatever interval you use for the Fourier series" - how does one specify that when writing a series?

Comment: See [Fourier series on general interval $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1399900)

Comment: In the very beginning he says $f:[-π,π] →ℝ$. But isn't $f$ defined for all $x$? Like we define $f(x)=x^2$ in $(-π,π]$ and $f(x+2π)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @HritRoy This is why the word "restricting" is there. Initially, the function defined for all $x$. We _restrict_ it to $x\in [-\pi, \pi)$. Then we extend it periodically.

Comment: Oh I missed the last part. Restrict, then extend. Makes sense.