# Fourier series of a function on interval $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

We assume that the function $f(x)$  is piecewise continuous on the interval $[-L,L]$. Using the substitution $x = \frac{{Ly}}{\pi } (-\pi\leq y \leq\pi)$, we can convert it into the function $F(y)=f(\frac{Ly}{\pi})$ which is defined and integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$

And we get
$$f\left( x \right) = \frac{{{a_0}}}{2} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left( {{a_n}\cos \frac{{n\pi x}}{L} + {b_n}\sin\frac{{n\pi x}}{L}} \right)}$$

Now how generalize on interval $[a,b]$? I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399900/fourier-series-on-general-interval-a-b) but still not sure about this.

It says take $L=\frac{b-a}{2}$.But in this way if $y\in[-\pi,\pi]$ then $\frac{Ly}{\pi} \in [\frac{a-b}{2},\frac{b-a}{2}]$. But we want it to be in the interval $[a,b]$.Sorry if this is trivial question but I am currently stuck on it.

Comment: Note that you want to change an interval from $[a,b]$ into $[c,d]$ whilst retaining the order of the function. Allow a linear substitution $c = xa + y$ and $d = xb + y$. You know the values of $a, b, c, d$, so you should be able to find $x$ and $y$. Then, you pass every value through the linear substitution $L(v) = xv + y$.

Comment: @egglog Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @egglog Where is used $L=\frac{b-a}{2}$ in what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer after thinking hard about problem but not sure if it is correct.

We want to write fourier series of a function on interval $(a,b]$. Let $b-a=2L$ and make function $f(x)$ periodic with period $2L$. Because function has period $2L$ instead of $(a,b]$ we can write fourier series on interval $(-L,L]$ and for this we have already formulas . Then we change $L$ with $\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

@egglog,@unit 1991, I think that
First, translating $x\in[a, b]\mapsto t+\frac{a+b}{2}$ for $t\in\left[-\frac{b-a}{2}, \frac{b-a}{2}\right]$;

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1795765)